# Conversion of date and time columns in Timestamps from Excel file in Python

Tags: python, arrays, string, datetime, timestamp

I want to convert the following date and time into timestamp. Later this timestamp and temperature column would use for regression algorithm. But basic thing I am stuck is to convert date and time column into single column of Timestamp. On internet I haven't found any example code that relates to my task.

[image]

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import time
filename = r'C:\Users\Windows 10\Desktop\bilal1.csv'
df = pd.read_csv(filename)
# Merging Date and Time columns
#conversion of  string Date time into Python Date time object
df['datetime2'] = pd.to_datetime (df['datetime'])
df['datetime']=df.iloc[:,0] + ' ' + df.iloc[:, 1]
Timestamp4 = time.strptime(['datetime2'], '%Y-%d-%m %H:%M:%S')
time_epoch = time.mktime(Timestamp4)
```

TypeError: strptime() argument 0 must be str, not << class 'list' >>

Comment: you can use python `datetime` for converting string type of date into a datetime format and after that create a column and save result.

Comment: `df['Timestamp'] = df['Date'].str + df['Time'].srt` might work